# Color of the sky

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, hard-science, atmosphere

I know the default will be blue, but just HOW blue, i.e., wavelength in nanometers?  I have a world with the following stats:

- Radius: 4628 km.
- Mass:  .35 Earth (2,09076 x 10^24 kg).
- Atmospheric Density: .88 Earths.
- Scale height: 14.63 km.
- Atm. Composition:

  - N2: 72%
  - O2: 19.6%
  - CH4 (Methane): .04%
  - CO2: .02%
  - Ar: 8.34%
  - Plus trace like ozone, water vapor, etc.
- Temperature: 299 K (25,85 °C)
- Solar Insolation: 1.04 (relative to Earth)
- It orbits a G3V star:

  - Temperature 5,756 K (5,482,85 °C)
  - Peak radiation: 503 nm.

What would be the formula for calculating the exact shade of blue? What factors do I need to keep in mind?

Comment: What do yo mean with `atmosphere density`? Maybe you want to say `atmospheric pressure`.

Comment: The shade of blue varies, and it's not monochromatic.  It's a collection of wavelengths from Rayleigh and Mie scattering.

Comment: All the little particles coming into contact with sunlight is what gives our sky its colors. Thus, it really depends on the color of the particles. Larger objects will give more complexity to the color as well, such as clouds, damp air, etc.

Comment: Even on this planet, the exact shade of blue varies. Sometimes that shade of blue is pink, or orange, or even greenish.

Comment: This feels relevant https://xkcd.com/1145/

Comment: Also this https://xkcd.com/1818/

Answer (score 14):

The answer to this depends on surprisingly *few* factors.  In fact, the only things you will need to consider are your atmospheric depth and your sun's output spectrum.

The blue color of the sky is predominantly caused by [Rayleigh Scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering), which is the deflection of electromagnetic waves as they travel through a medium of dipoles.  To get the correct color, you draw a ray from the observer out into space.  At each point along this line, you determine the intensity of the light hitting that point.  The intensity of Rayleigh scattering  is defined by the equation:

$$ I = I_0 \frac{ 1+\cos^2 \theta }{2 R^2} \left( \frac{ 2 \pi }{ \lambda } \right)^4 \left( \frac{ n^2-1}{ n^2+2 } \right)^2 \left( \frac{d}{2} \right)^6$$

Where R is the distance to the particle, theta is the scattering angle, lambda is the wavelength, n is the refractive index, and d is the diameter of the particle.

Of course, none of these are dependent on your medium except n, the refractive index, which will be roughly the same for your planet's atmosphere as is Earth's air.

What this means is that the effect of Rayleigh Scattering is going to be pretty much the same as you see on Earth.  (There's Mie scattering as well, but Rayleigh dominates).  The only difference will be the atmospheric depth, which affects the path lengths you will be integrating along (both the path length from sun to particle and path length from particle to ground observer).

The color of the sky will, of course, also be dependent on the star you choose.  However, since the star you chose is *really* close to that of the sun, you should expect almost perfectly earth-like behaviors.  The only difference will be from that path length difference.  I believe that the result will be a darker blue with less scattering.

And, since you asked for a "shade" of blue and this scattering effect is multispectral, we can collapse it into a single shade as viewed by a human using the [CIE standard observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#CIE_standard_observer).

Comment: Whether Rayleigh dominates strongly depends on weather. In some places you can often see silvery-blue to almost white sky due to very thin clouds — with the Sun shining at the same time from the same location in the sky.

Answer (score 6):

### Your atmospheric density

The refractive index of a material [depends on the density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Density). You've stated yours is $88\%$ of Earth's, the [refractive index of Earth's air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Typical_values) is $n_{air} = 1.000293$. For gasses $n-1$ is directly proportional to the density of the material, so:
$$n_{air} - 1 \propto \rho_{air}$$
$$n_{new} - 1 \propto \rho_{new} = \rho_{air} \times 0.88 $$
$$\frac{n_{new} - 1}{n_{air} - 1} = \frac{\rho_{air} \times 0.88}{\rho_{air}} = 0.88 $$
$$ n_{new} = 1 + 0.88(1.000293-1) = 1.00025784$$

So your new refractive index is slightly lower than that on Earth.

If we look at rayleigh scattering, assuming all other constants are the same:
$$ I \propto \left( \frac{ 1 }{ \lambda } \right)^4 \left( \frac{ n^2-1}{ n^2+2 } \right)^2$$

comparing the intensities for your new refractive index:

$$I_{new} = I_{Earth} \cfrac{\left( \cfrac{ n_{new}^2-1}{ n_{new}^2+2 } \right)^2}{\left( \cfrac{ n_{air}^2-1}{ n_{air}^2+2 } \right)^2} = I_{Earth} \times 0.774 $$

We get a $77\%$ reduction in the light you're scattering through the atmosphere across all wavelengths.

As a result your sky will be a more washed out blue - the lower refractive index will mean the light scatters less so the distinction will be lower - but the sky will be darker since the intensity of scattered light is so reduced.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong...when I ran the equation (because I would like to do this for myself) my answers came up COMPLETELY different.  Could you walk me through it?  Thank you for your answers, though. I must admit I was a little surprised by the final result. But, then again, real life contains many surprises itself...

Comment: @Mike Which result was different for you ($n_{new}$ or $I_{new}$)? I've run it a couple of times and get the same answer.

Comment: Inew (sorry, no italics on this thing)...came up .99966958 (it was actually a bit longer, but I just wanted to give the general sense).  As far as  nnew, I came up with .00000000006256.   Clearly, I messed up somewhere. (This was usually my problem in math class...I THOUGHT I was doing the equation right.)  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: What was your equation for $n_{new}$? The problem does seem to be there.

Comment: Honestly, I entered what I saw there in your post.

Comment: @Mike The equation is right (I had entered it wrong but not different enough to get what you got [here is my calculation of $n_{new}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B0.88*(1.000293-1)) and [here is $I_{new}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(+(1.00025784%5E2+-+1)%2F(1.00025784%5E2+%2B2)+)%5E2+%2F+(+(1.000293%5E2+-+1)%2F(1.000293%5E2+%2B2)+)%5E2)

Comment: For fractions which themselves involve fractions (such as your calculation of $I_{new}$), `\cfrac` renders much more readably than plain `\frac`. You can see the effect yourself with my edit.

Comment: Ok, I see now wherein my errors lie....I neglected to use enough parentheses! Thank you very much for your patience. How would the refractive index change if it was a more methane-dominated atmosphere, or ammonia?

Comment: @Mike For gasses the [refractive index is directly proportional to the density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Density) so if you compare the masses of the chemicals you're swapping out you can check whether your refractive index will go up and down. You can use the refractive index of air as it is and compare to get rid of the constant and get your new refractive index in terms of the refractive index of Earth's air now. (Hope that made sense).